# Local Reverse Image search for comparison

Tags: windows, offline, image-recognition

At work we often get asked to search for assets on hard drive based off of a screen shot. So I am looking for a reverse image search that searches a computers Hard Drive. We want to use it to search our collection of stock images and videos for ones that are specifically requested.

We seek a comparison search program that just looks at a single image that is input and searches and outputs a similar image from a specific folder. 
NOT to DELETE or MOVE but just want to know where it is.

Most of the ones we have tried like VisPics only wants to delete or move it doesnt offer the option to open in explorer/finder, nor does it allow us to input a single image, they all ask for whole folder inputs.

We just need single input visual image search for our hard drive. Anyone know of anything like that? For Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Would the [Picture edition of DupeGuru](https://www.hardcoded.net/dupeguru_pe/) be sufficient?  The tool allows you to specify multiple directories, say, one containing your collection and another with the search candidate, so this would seem to come close to your requirements.

Though it is meant to find/remove (near)duplicates of images, it initially displays a list of the possible matches which you can click to display etc.

You can specify directories as "reference only" so they won't be removable and, I also suspect, speed up the search process. The preferences settings can adjust the closeness of matches as well as allowing matches of different dimensions.

One downside though is that sometimes it doesn't seem particularly fast.

Comment: I've looked at that one before, and it was a bit to slow for our massive library of media files so much so, that I didnt even think it was working. But I guess could give it another shot.

Comment: I suspect that it's important to have the "library" directories marked as reference to stop it wasting its time looking for duplicates there.

Having said that, I just decided to give it a test with ~5000 4k*3k images and on my PC it looks like it's limited by the speed of the disk. The disk light's flashing like crazy but the CPU is barely loaded.  I'm thinking that if I had a directory of "thumbnail" versions, the process would be a lot faster.