# macOS app to check if an image is already on the computer?

Tags: osx, search, macos, image-recognition, duplicate-files

I'm looking for a photo de-duper app for Mac, but from a different angle than normal.

If I download a new image from the web, I want to know if I already have it on my Mac or not.

I have had trouble finding a Mac duplicate photo finder that allows me to scan like a reverse image search. They only allow me to scan whole folders to find any and all duplicates, but I only want to find dupes of *one* image that I specify. If no dupes exist, then it would return nothing.

This is basically [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31963/local-reverse-image-search-for-comparison) but for macOS.

Answer (score 1):

It's unfortunately a paid app, but the powerful and sleek [PhotoSweeper](https://overmacs.com/) can do a local reverse image search on your Mac.

Here's how:

1. Open the app and choose "Side to Side Mode".

[image]
2. Drag and drop an image into the left-hand pane. Select parent folder to recursively search within such as your Mac's home folder.

[image]
3. Click 'Compare' button. Options pop up for how strictly or loosely you want to scan for matches. Press 'Start'.

It may take a while depending on how many images you have.

[image]
Here's the result in my example. It found a dupe image on my hard drive, `small_edited.png`:

[image]
It even apparently can do videos.

What would make things much faster is an app that pre-indexes the Mac's images instead of re-scanning them every time you do a local reverse image search. That would make for a superior answer.